# How to fix 'cannot resolve symbol 'fo:root' ' in .xsl file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-fop

Ok so I am new to xsl and am creating a template that will be used to create a PDF file from an XML file using Apache FOP and am currently getting a cannot resolve symbol error for every 'fo:' tag

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                                       page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" color="red" font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold">
                        Hello, <xsl:value-of select="patient/patientDetails/firstName"/>!
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Previously, everything was working fine and created a basic hello file, I tried making changes and found that it still creates a file when the application is run, however every time I try and open the PDF file, for example in a browser, it acts as though I am downloading it eg. bringing up a dialogue box asking if I want to save or open. If i press open with (any browser) it just brings up the dialogue box again in a new tab.

I reverted back to the basic hello file, but am now getting the cannot resolve symbol 'fo:' for every fo: tag, and still the same problem with the looping dialogue box when attempting to open the PDF file in a browser.

Comment: it runs... : ``java -cp "%LOCALCLASSPATH%" org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process  -IN  test_fop.xml -XSL  test_fop.xsl -OUT test_fop.fo`` , then ``fop -fo test_fop.fo -pdf test_fop.pdf``

Comment: opening the PDF file in a browser has nothing to do with fop, i think. Check for browser add-on to be able to open pdf....

Comment: Thanks! After not being able to open the file in a pdf viewer, i inspected the files and found I had missed the '.pdf' off the file name and so it was only saving as a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IntelliJ then you can try add a schema.
*File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks-> Schemas and DTDs*
then in "External schemas and DTDs:" click "+" and type "fo.xsd". click "OK" -> Apply -> ok